# Stack Overflow and homework questions

Tags: discussion, homework

I've used Stack Overflow over the years, but lately it seems the main purpose of Stack Overflow is for students to post their homework and ask for "help" without even trying to run the code in an IDE or on the command line.

What can we do with a question that is clearly a homework? Can we flag it as homework?

The problem is, people will go ahead and write the answer, robbing the student of a learning opportunity.

Comment: The homework tag is deprecated, meaning it should not be used any longer.

Comment: This is actually a continuation of a very old discussion.  There *used* to be a [tag:homework] tag, but it was removed.  You can review some of the old discussion in [Can we now discourage the use of and burninate the homework tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag), and there is a [meta-tag:faq] entry on MSE for [guidelines for asking homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?lq=1)

Comment: recommended reading: **[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)**

Answer (score 58):

First off, no one is being "robbed" of a learning opportunity. The bargain they're making may be somewhat Faustian, but... They're making it willingly.

That doesn't make these good questions however. Many of them are poorly-written, rife with misspellings and/or raw text copied directly from the assignment. And an awful lot of them never bother to ask a clear question, leaving it to the unfortunate Daniels answering to divine both the problem *and* its solution.

So what can we do? Well, if you don't think the question is useful, if it's lacking in research or a clear question... **Then downvote it.** If there's no clear question to answer *at all*, then flag it and choose to Close as Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: if memory serves, Faust also bargained willingly

Comment: @gnat that is why `Faustian` makes sense.

Comment: @gnat Not "but" meaning but, but "but" meaning "and"!  [to the rhythm of Run DMC's Peter Piper]

Answer (score 39):

Don't flag questions as "homework."  There's nothing moderators can do about that.

There's a specific admonishment in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work
>   you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the
>   difficulty you are having solving it.

If a user is clearly just trying to get their homework answered without any effort on their part, I typically close the question, putting that description in the custom close reason.

That said, the manner in which student choose to learn is their problem, not ours.

Comment: True that it is their problem.  It becomes your problem when they're later working next to you.  But SO isn't the problem; the problem is lazy students.  There have always been, and there always will be lazy students, and they do get jobs.

Comment: _Don't flag questions as "homework."_ ... THIS!  We get far too many flags about homework.  These flags make my decline finger twitchy.

Comment: As long as the user knows the answer by the time they finish their course, surely it's fine? I don't care why someone wants to learn, whether it's to improve, fix a bug at work, or to gain a degree... the important thing is that they're writing better code.

Comment: If user adds a question just get his work done, how to flag those ?
or should we mark it as "Requires Editing" ?