# How to avoid students misusing the Stack Overflow website

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm working as a software engineer in a company, active in hardware and software development. As such, regularly I am faced with a complex situation I can't always handle, hence I use Stack Overflow regularly.

However recently I see another way of using this website: typical homework questions for students: I have the impression that more and more this website gets used by students who, instead of thinking for themselves, just put their homework questions here on the site and let other people solve it.

This obviously is bad, as well for the student, as well for the other students who do their homework in an honest way, as for this website.

How can this be handled?

Comment: Might be worth a read [Homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/stack-overflow-and-homework-questions) although it deals with the issue from another perspective, there are some links / info in there that might be useful to you.

Comment: This is already out of control.  Some students put so much effort into disguising their no-effort assignments that they may be better off just doing the work themselves.

Comment: There are a lot more of them lately, but that isn't the core problem.  The real issue is that SO gets entirely too many questions.  Too many to still effectively moderate.  Not unsubtle either, it needs ~5000 questions per day less.  Making the site less accessible is the only real solution.  Getting *any* proposal towards that goal upvoted in meta, or for the company to agree, is a pretty remote outcome right now.  It needs to get a lot worse before it can get better.

Comment: Part of the problem is that *other people **do** solve it*. If every student who just dumped a paste of their assignment (whether homework or not) and asked for the solution was sent packing with a closed question and no answer, that might dissuade others.

Comment: Point them to [this](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems), apart from the regular actions you take.

Comment: I agree.  I suspect students are trying to get homework answers here.  I think I will start just giving them the logic and some of the code, so they can see how it works.  I'm going to stop writing the code for them.  Albeit, answering questions and reading other's answers increases my own knowledge base.  I've learned way more just reading here than what I've helped.

Comment: Maybe a "Suspected Homework" flag would be fun, especially if it sidetracked the post for 2 weeks when the due date is surely past. I say, "Fun" because when I taught I saw some creative attempts to get out of doing homework.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the user included a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem and a description of the difficulties faced, it will make a homework question a valid question on Stack Overflow.

If you think there is no effort at all then you can use the flags to close the question and also you can use the question downvotes:

> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy,
>   no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps
>   dangerously incorrect.

Comment: One recurring problem I see is that **even the sloppy, no-effort-expended posts** which already got downvotes and close votes still get serious, complete answers. Would you suggest downvoting these as well?

Comment: @Jongware I think this issue is mainly because there are rep points to be gained (and some people seem to get crazy over imaginary points on the internet...) and it has been suggested we revert this points. However, as you can also see in the answers to this question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255782/shouldnt-we-revert-reputation-gains-for-answers-to-closed-questions there are good reasons for not doing so.

Comment: There is knowledge to be gained as well as rep points. Students who ask for others to solve their homework for them are providing random people on the internet the opportunity to learn (or refine their knowledge of) something. I point this out because even if there were no reputation system, I still think sloppy, no-effort questions would get answered.