# On the interpretation and reaction towards "homework questions" false positives

Tags: discussion

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964391/print-all-possible-combination-of-a-number) for a few minutes, along with its respective votes, comments, and edits, all of this got me thinking a bit, if maybe we're getting to aggressive into identifying so-called "homework questions", which, according to several sources, such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255499/5249858), [that one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812), and [the other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253794/5249858), aren't by themselves bad questions, or questions meriting downvoting+flagging+close votes combos.

Anyway, that's not the case here. Let me explain it a bit more. If you look at the question's edit history, buried at the bottom is the original post, right? Well, it turns out that such a post contained two misleading sentences:

- `It would be really helpful if both recursion and iterative solutions are provided.`: This sentence clearly looks like a homework-style requirement, and so was the question though to be so.
- `...such that the digit in the n'th is never greater than the n'th digit of the given number.`: This sentence was unintelligible, and so was the question though to be poorly/lazyly written, if not copy-pasted.

Then, after about 11 minutes after the original post, the second comment stated: `Stack overflow is not a homework or a literal 'free'lancer service. Don't ask people to do the work for you.`, and as a result, the question immediately got two downvotes. This is my first point. As soon as someone comments that SO is not for homework, downvotes, flags, and what-not come in.

The OP then proceeded to clarify all of this, and to state that English is not his first language. He said that the first sentence's intention was for him to learn about recursive and iterative styles, and so the first conflicting sentence was to be interpreted as `"I would like to practice recursion and iterative styles, and so it would be helpful if an answer could provide examples relating to this proper problem"`. The second sentence was apparently kind of a typo/translation error, and not any sort of copy-paste. After editing both sentences, and asking for reconsidering the votes, the question was fortunately upvoted twice.

The OP also clarified that it was *not* a homework/job assignment, but rather something for himself to practice and learn. He reiterated this with by adding a message at the top of the question to avoid further issues.

This is definitely not the first time I have seen this kind of situations. However, I am unable to find those previous examples. So, how should questions be considered to be "homework", and what should be the behavior towards non-perfect-English posts?

Just because of two misleading sentences, the community reacted in a harsh way, and it happened not to even be a homework question in the first place. Is this the way we're supposed to behave?

Comment: I felt really bad when people down-voted my question. I am sorry to say this but the SO community has been harsh, particularly with 'C' tags. This will degrade the usage of SO in a long run.

I feel that a reason has be provided if a question is down-voted and that should be a mandatory thing.

Comment: *"...as a result, the question immediately got two downvotes"*...You have no way of knowing if that is true. It may be but since votes are anonymous you have no evidence. of that statement.

Comment: And guess what one of the person who commented harshly on my post, didn't provide an answer nor any help once the situation has been re-clarified. What right do such people have to down-vote if they are really not providing any help?

Comment: Although this may not have been a homework question...it's effectively asking for a tutorial...which is equally off-topic...I think.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I was looking at the number of views and I am sure that the people who commented were the one's who down-voted.

Comment: My experience on StackOverflow.com is that downvoting is often hastily done, by "drive-by downvoters". It's unfortunate. Often times, a downvote really should be a vote to close, not a downvote. There's probably way to much of this sort of thing going on to properly moderate it.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I am asking for an approach/idea of how to solve it. I have tried first before seeking an answer. The question is a decent one and there are no duplicates. If this continues, I am sorry but the community is in danger.

Comment: *"Often times, a downvote really should be a vote to close, not a downvote."* Now that I agree with. I often Close Vote without Down Voting...a question might be clear, and well researched but still off-topic.

Comment: @Paulie_D: (Sorry for the late response). I have no *proof* that it happened, but I know it did because I was looking at the question just before the comment, and it had a score of zero. After the comment, a downvote almost immediately followed. Then did another one or three minutes later.

Comment: *"Knowledge"* and fact are not necessarily the same. The world used to be flat you know.

Comment: Question in current state shows some code, but it is not clear if code is in any way related to the question and what, if any issues are present in the code. And there is no question...

Comment: This question is not about whether such a question was valid/well-written/decent or not, but on its interpretation as homework (see this same question).

Comment: @Ravi: I'm always puzzled what posters of such questions want to achieve by stating essentially "I want to learn, solve this problem for me". Care to explain what are you looking for?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I think he's clear enough on that he wants/needs to solve the problem he appropriate postulates, and shows the code as to give us an idea of had he has done/proof-of-concept-that-he-has-done-something. Maybe the question is too indirect/vague?

Comment: @KemyLand this is clearly "homework" question from SO point of view - something one need to solve that has no practical usage beyond gaining *particular* knowledge (like `for` loop or other single concept) which not necessary given by some teacher (could be self-imposed, some competition, interview question).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: [That is not SO's point of view about what is a homework question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). And, as it happens, he *is* trying to gain knowledge, but at the same time, he presents a proper problem, not something that a "what's-a`for`-loop-question" would do.

Comment: @KemyLand the question clearly does not fall under "debugging" (as there is no information about the code). Not really sure how to classify that.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: A question doesn't have to classify under "debugging". For example, if you're trying to get an algorithm to solve a problem, such as this question's OP does. True, maybe the code below is not the best way to illustrate this, but if its removed from the question (and not touching any non-code word), then everything is clearer. The question is not *lacking*, but including his own code, which is apparently irrelevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106122/discussion-between-alexei-levenkov-and-kemyland).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I think In-order to achieve practical usage basics are necessary, be it a single concept or more than one without which the code we generate might not be well optimized, I am trying to strengthen my basic and hence I came up with a question which till now no one has answered and only few good people have tried. Please let me know if this is not the forum for this.

Comment: I did look carefully at this question and decided to just ignore it.  Unusually, this is a question I did not down or close-vote.  I do notice here, however 'it happened not to even be a homework question in the first place'.  I would like to know how you know that?  Do you know the question poster?  Are you on the same course and know that no such assignments have been issued?

Comment: @MartinJames: Of course, everything we know is from the OP's words. Basing upon there, and the fact that so far he has been open to editing/removing faulty sentences, I wouldn't expect it to be homework in any sense of the word, neither do I think it may be.

Comment: You see, the problem I have with such statements, and phrases like 'false positives', is that I see no justification for them apart from the OP's statements in the question and comments.  Since some OP's are blatant liars who will post whatever it takes to get a homework answer written for them, OP 'it's not homework' statements/comments are irrelevant.

Comment: Never underestimate the desire of students to get all their work done for them!  I still have no position on the OP, and will continue to ignore it and apply no votes, but I am somewhat dismayed that whatever the OP posts seems to be swallowed by many SO contributors hook, line and sinker.

Comment: @MartinJames: We have no proof about what he's saying, nor about what I'm saying, or what you're saying. This is the Internet, after all. Proofs aren't that usual here. This is all based upon patterns and simple trusting. Otherwise, it would be impossible to answer questions, as you'ld never know if they're homework or not...

Comment: 'Simple trusting' will get you abused on SO.  I'm afraid that many posters don't give a toss about you, or how much time they suck away from answering better questions.  All they care about is getting their work done by someone else for free, and thye don't care what they need to say to achieve that aim.

Comment: @MartinJames: It can happen, but going to either extreme is dangerous. I'm just assuming that the OP is being sincere, but wouldn't trust absolutely everything he says. However, I have a good faith in that what he posted is not homework at all. If the question doesn't treats itself as homework, then it's not homework, for practical purposes. I mean, how do you know if this same question is not itself homework? Some people are better at hiding the facts, and others are better at looking like they are doing so, though they aren't.

Comment: Ravi needs to learn to use a debugger. Step through code. See why the output is occurring as it happens. There are a few valid reasons to downvote and close this question. It just depends who stumbles upon it and how generous with their time Ravi gets. Like a free 30 minutes. Maybe 2 hours. Depending on his skill level.

Comment: On the other matter, I for one could care less if it is a homework question or not. Those comments aren't very useful for anyone.

Comment: OK, IIRC, the question was originally somewhat unclear,  Now it's had 11 edits, it's somewhat clearer.  While I could not downvote it as a no-effort homework dump, I can close vote it for no aparrent debugging done.

Comment: @Ravi: "*What right do such people have to down-vote if they are really not providing any help?*" Um, no. You do not suddenly gain the *right* to have your question answered just because you posted it. If someone looks at a poorly worded question and downvotes it, they have no responsibility to *monitor* that question to see if it becomes better later on. If they leave a comment on it, it is not their responsibility to come back later to see if the post has improved. You are ***not entitled*** to help.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Agreed, I am not entitled to help from anyone, but that doesn't mean I should question the judgment of the people who simply down-voted without comments nor help. I am relatively new here and also I am not as experienced as many but if people like me are intimidated by down-votes then the next generation will not be benefited by SO and the cycle breaks quickly.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I open SO daily and surf the 'C' tags and all I see is negative comments & down-votes while low quality questions tagged in 'Python' receive positive responses... Is this because people who learn/do stuff in 'C' are dumb? No. Is this because the SO community of 'C' is far advanced that if I beginner posts a question it might look lame to them? Maybe. But, all I am trying to say is to be more open while judging, please don't jump into conclusions without proper information and give the new generation more space and freedom.

Comment: @Drew: I am pretty sure you got me wrong, pardon me/my question for such appearance. I was primarily looking for an algorithm to solve it. That way I wanted to learn the best method from best minds which I believe are at SO. But unfortunately people ganged up against me. Even after such heavy discussion not a single person provided me an answer or something similar. I have not asked people to debug my code but I kept it there just to show that I have tried.

Comment: The point of homework or, ahem, a personal exercise is *never* to get a working program.  There is no ticked-off customer behind it that won't pay you when your code doesn't work.  Nobody actually cares that the program works, most likely thing that happens next is that it is thrown away.  The point is to exercise problem solving.  Asking somebody else to solve the problem is completely pointless.  The only constructive thing is to ask *how* to address the problem, fairly doomed to be closed as "too broad" of course.

Comment: @Ravi I don't know how I got you wrong from what I said. I was saying that you need some debugging skills. That is meant as constructive criticism. You can create a chat room and we can get that question going again. People are here to help you. Comments that you are making keep talking about "ganging up" and "if this continues" etc. Basically your first 3 or 4 comments up top seem unfounded and off target. People do not owe you anything. People do not need to leave comments or come back later after a vote (DV or close vote). Like I said, create a chat room

Comment: Perhaps you can't create a room. [Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106153) it is.

Comment: @HansPassant: As you rightly said, I have asked people on how to address the problem if not solve it. There was only one person who actually tried to help and the remaining were worried only about why this particular question is asked and why does he want answer for this question or is this a homework question or not etc. Sorry to say this but I realized one thing yesterday, SO is helpful to newbies only by the rich collection of previous questions and nothing more.

Comment: Well, you got that pretty wrong.  SO is helpful because of answers to practical answerable questions.  If you don't ask such a question then *you* are not helping.

Comment: Such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945332) . It is not a practical question. If explained in sufficient detail in steps, it is a number theory / math-head question that is about 2 pages long. I can answer that in java or c# but why bother.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> homework questions, [...] according to several sources, [...] aren't by themselves bad questions

That's true.  The fact that the question is homework doesn't make it a bad question, but an *overwhelming* majority of homework related questions are bad questions.  They're not bad because they're homework, they're bad for other reasons.  It's *possible* to ask a good question about a problem that happens to be homework related, but it's *very* rare, and not the case with this question.

> He said that the first sentence's intention was for him to learn about recursive and iterative styles, and so the first conflicting sentence was to be interpreted as "I would like to practice recursion and iterative styles, and so it would be helpful if an answer could provide examples relating to this proper problem"

And *that's not a good question to ask on SO*, so it's *appropriate* for it to be downvoted.

> The OP also clarified that it was not a homework/job assignment

As you've already pointed out, this is irrelevant.  It's a bad question because it's a bad question, not because it's a homework question.

> He reiterated this with by adding a message at the top of the question to avoid further issues.

And this was edited out of the question because, as has already been said, this is irrelevant.

> So, how should questions be considered to be "homework"

Whether a question is related to homework or not is irrelivant.  Questions should be judged on their merits, which, in this case, is to say that it's a very low quality question that just dumps a bunch of code, says, "It doesn't work" and asks for people to fix it.

> and what should be the behavior towards non-perfect-English posts?

If the problems with the language are so bad that the question cannot be understood, close it as "unclear", if the question can be understood despite the language issues, then it should be edited to fix those problems.  I should note that the English language problems are not particularly concerning with this question.  That's not what makes it bad. It's bad because it just dumps a bunch of code and asks people to fix it, and that isn't a good question, regardless of the quality of the English or whether it's homework or not.

> Just because of two misleading sentences, the community reacted in a harsh way, and it happened not to even be a homework question in the first place. Is this the way we're supposed to behave?

I don't even see any indication that those sentences are why the question received a poor reception.  It received a poor reception because it's a low quality question.

Answer (score 5):

The is no evidence at all that the votes on the question have anything to do with the question being a "homework" question.

There exist these two comments that point toward this being homework:

> Stack overflow is not a homework or a literal 'free'lancer service. Don't ask people to do the work for you.

... and ...

> @Ravi: `It would be really helpful if both recursion and iterative solutions are provided.`: That looks pretty much like homework...

And the second of those two comments was made by yourself.

The second comment is a far more aggressive "homework" accusation than the first, and if you are personally seeing a problem with the negative reaction that Stack Overflow has to homework questions, then it would probably be a good idea to stop accusing questions of being homework questions.

The first comment is nothing more than an accusation of laziness.  The first comment accuses the post of being exactly what the downvote option exists for (per its tooltip):

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

And if we look at the original form of the question, or several of the forms of the question up to and after the time that this meta post was opened, that was an absolutely perfect description of the original form of the question.

So much so that I had cast a close vote under the reason of "Unclear what you are asking."

Whether this (or any other question) on the site is homework is completely irrelevant.  There is nothing inherently wrong with questions that happen to be based on homework (or office work).

The problem is with questions that are lazy, show no research effort, are unclear, etc.  And this question absolutely met those criteria until at least the 8th revision which was made a full 20 minutes after this meta post was opened.