# Question deleted after edit while "On hold"

Tags: support, deleted-questions, on-hold

I ran into a case which is kind of frustrating to me.

1. OP (which is a new user), posted a question of low quality, and the point of the question was hard to understand.
2. The question have been downvoted rapidly (-3).
3. I tried with an other user to understand the question by asking questions to the OP
4. The question have been put "On hold" for the reason "unclear"
5. I tried to help OP to increase the quality of the question, he made poor edits.
6. I finally edited it by myself, with the elements of the comments.
7. Edit was accepted
8. I was waiting for the question to be reopened to help the user
9. Question is deleted.

I don't understand why the question have been deleted. Here was the link of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57752342/how-to-get-the-perform-a-difference-in-each-sublist-of-a-list. It has been deleted "for reasons of moderation".

It's a bit frustrating to me because I spent time improving the question, and I had an answer to provide but I wasn't able to because question was on hold.

Screenshot of post: 
[image]

Screenshot of edit: 
[image]

Comment: @JeanneDark That's untrue. The question was deleted by 3 users with enough rep to cast delete votes (>20K rep). Only they can explain their motivations for casting a delete vote, but I guess they didn't deem the edit sufficient to allow re-opening. As a sidenote, never edit in _Thank you for the future help_ on behalf of someone else. Thank you is considered noise and doesn't belong in questions, I'd have rejected that edit

Comment: @ErikA Ok, thank you for the sidenote, I will take it into account for next times. This is probably the reason why someone voted to reject the edit.

Comment: To be frank, I don't understand why people spend effort deleting questions like these. I mean, it's closed already with no answers and a negative score. If it fails to reopen in a few days time it'll be deleted automatically by the roomba script. So all deleting does is prevent the OP from improving the post in a way that makes this answerable. Feels wrong somehow.

Comment: Also, the edited title doesn't make a lot of sense. And I'm not 100% convinced the edited question merits reopening. But maybe that kind of thing can survive in the python tag. I do not frequent the tag, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Quick deletion of non-salvageable questions has the positive side-effect that prevents the post to accumulate further downvotes. If a question **can't** be edited into shape reasonably, deletion helps both the site to keep a higher signal/noise ratio, and helps the poster because they avoid being downvoted into a q-ban.

Comment: @yivi - the only problem with that is that it may prevent the OP from posting an improved version of the question. If the post is heavily down-voted before being deleted it may trigger the automatic question ban.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, it's not a perfect system. In theory the user could edit their question while deleted, and flag afterwards. With the kind of questions we are talking about, I'm not sure if that's really on the cards. But if the user was already at the point of q-banning when the deletion occurred, they were already _very_ short of options.

Comment: There are substantial "fairness" problems at play.  The [python] tag gets a lot more questions than can be answered by the available contributors, answer rate is only 50%.  So how many programmers with a decent Python question did not get help because y'all were working on rescuing this one?  Not where it ends, this question is likely to receive more DVs, it already does.  Putting this user in a very deep hole that is going to get him banned with no decent way to get out of it.  Clearly this has to stop *somewhere*, bullet 4 is about the right time for almost any question.

Comment: @yivi they'd have to keep a record of the question URL off site as it disappears from their profile as soon as it's deleted.

Comment: @ChrisF It does disappear after 30 days, yes. I was still thinking about a user trying to react to the situation as it unfolded, not coming back at it a month afterwards. But again, a user that was already that close to q-banning, had very little to choose from. It's maybe unfortunate for them, but the 'finite resources' angle that Hans brings up does have merit.

Comment: OP hasn't posted any code. This seems like a homework problem with no effort. I'd close it as *Too Broad* until OP adds their effort.

Comment: @adiga that behavior presents another problem: it being “homework” is not a reason to close as too broad. There have been more and more instances of closers abusing close reasons; and so now we have to keep an eye out for that.

Comment: @yivi it disappears from their profile immediately. They have to know about and click the "show recently deleted questions" option to find it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker it should be closed not because it is homework but because OP has not made any effort to solve the problem or hasn't posted their effort. It is clearly mentioned in this faq "*Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed.*" [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/3082296)

Comment: @adiga lack of effort is not a reason to close a question. We even got rid of "minimal understanding" because closers were abusing it for this reason.  Yes, this FAQ lists what a user should do (what is 'ethical'). Our close reasons list what is 'legal'. Homework without effort is 'legal', even though it's not 'ethical'; depending on how it's worded.

Comment: "_Homework without effort is 'legal'_" @GeorgeStocker That does sound like the opposite of what [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states: "_Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above: ... 3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._" (leaving aside whether that applies to this question.)

Comment: @Ivar now we're delving into "time to ask a question on meta" where you ask what are the valid reasons to close a question that you think is homework, and what reasons to use. However, that has been asked and answered previously([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253794/16587), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288969/16587), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323713/16587), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252585/16587), [5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort)).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker you seem to be fixating on this being a homework question. If we disregard that aspect, should the question remain unclosed? The question seems poor, IMHO.

Comment: @script47 I only brought up homework because others did. I don’t see anywhere in the question where they say it’s homework. On to your question: I don’t see any issues in the question that merit closing according to our close reasons. Downvote? Maybe. Close? no.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I agree with the posts you link, but that doesn't change that _the_ official article about which topic's are allowed on SO explicitly state that questions asking homework help "_must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem_", which seem to contradict your comment. So either I'm misinterpreting your comment or that article, or one of them is incorrect.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker maybe we differ in our philosophies with regards to closing but surely that question is '*Too broad*'? It lists requirements and that's all. No indication to any prior attempts or anything of the sort or even any code (not that code is a requirement).

Comment: @Ivar: no indication from OP it's homework; even if it is; we have no close reason for "didn't show your work" on purpose. That's a reason to downvote, not close (see the hover over a question downvote if you do not believe me, or the references I cited previously in these comments).

Comment: @Script47: It asks an answerable question in python. What other 'requirements' would you need to answer it?  It's loads better than most requirements I've ever received as a programmer.  As Shog says, [Visible Effort By Itself is pointless](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388594/16587)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker just because a question is answerable doesn't make not broad or close vote worthy.

Comment: @Script47 you may want to re-read the close reason text for 'too broad': "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It is too broad because it just states the problem and there is no clue about what is the actual question here (beyond, write my code for me). We don't know whether OP does not know how to formulate the algorithm for the task, whether he does not know how to iterate through list, how to add items to list... he could be asking all of the above questions at once. That is what makes it too broad.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The policy since many years is that we no longer care _why_ someone asks a question, but hold all questions to the same quality standards. I believe the homework part in the [on-topic moderation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is merely a left-over from a time when we used to have a homework tag. _All_ questions must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @ChrisF I mentioned [a while ago at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332499/how-could-we-improve-our-planned-post-notice-improvements/332501#comment1084945_332501 "'I didn't notice any obstacles at all'") that in my experience questions deleted by 20K votes were quite comfortable for the case if I wanted to improve and retry (having a diamond you better keep in mind that mod deletes seemed different - still doable mind you but rather inconvenient)

Comment: @lundin closing questions (that are not debugging questions) for those reasons is not the policy, as the questions I linked to demonstrate.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker We don't moderate the site according to some random meta post by Shog, but by the link I gave you. Where you are mixing up 1) with 3). This wasn't a debug request so 1) doesn't apply. 3) does.

Comment: @Lundin Who decides what is homework help? The OP didn't state that in the question.  That notwithstanding; do you have a close reason that matches what #3 says? (This question is rhetorical, because there isn't one. We've adjudicated this issue at least a dozen times on meta. There is no reason to close questions because they didn't show what they tried (outside of debugging, of course).  You can try some mental gymnastics to try to make another fit even when it doesn't, but then you're fighting against written policies and we have to enforce those policies.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yes, "write the whole code for me" requests should be closed as too broad. And the point in this specific case isn't so much that they didn't show what they had tried, but rather that they failed to state what part they were having trouble with. Understanding the algorithm? Implementing it in Python? Getting the correct results? According to the text as stated presently, they are rather getting the correct results and have no problem to be solved. Though that part seems to be the result of bad edits.

Comment: I think that the fact that OP is a new user should be an element to take into account. New users need to be guided imho, instead of having their question "overmoderated" very fast (with close/delete), because this can affray new users.

Comment: The point _"there isn't a close reason that matches so shouldn't be closed"_ is kinda silly. The close reason list isn't exhaustive, nor the meaning of each of the close reasons uniquivocal, and furthermore users can use _custom close reasons_, which I believe it proves the close reasons are not the only gospel to follow. In this case, _too broad_ applies, IMO, because the question was not adequately scoped. You can try some mental gymnastics to see it as a good, on-topic question for the site, but we have written policies and community consensus that say that it is not.

Comment: @yivi if people are closing according to their gut and not according to the close reason text then they’re abusing the close system. When that happens, those questions should be flagged for moderator attention so we can send the closer a mod message and take further action to correct the situation as needed.

Comment: No, George. Users voting according to their own judgement is certainly **not** _"voting according to their gut"_, and it is not "abusing the close system". It's the way the system is designed: users interpret the guidance and community consensus and cast votes according to their judgement. It's personal opinion that as long as it is not fraudulent according to the rules of the site it is not "abuse".

Comment: And once more, the point of there being **custom** close reasons points very clearly that sometimes the list provided is not enough, and yet the question can be closed.

Comment: @yivi : Succinctly: Closing the above question as 'too broad' for the reasons you mentioned is abuse. Every question is a 'write this code for me question' when you get down to it; it's a matter of scope. the OP's question is well-scoped and answerable.  If you want to use a custom close reason, that's different than using a reason that doesn't fit consistently.

Comment: No George, it is not. Voting to close because you believe a question is not adequately scoped is not abuse, at all. I don't know exactly to what "reasons I mentioned" you refer, but voting to close because one believes a question is not adequately scoped and should be closed is not abuse.

Comment: I have not voted nor will I vote on that question, in the *"grand scheme of things"* it does not make much difference and is only tiring to see these wars, but I'm not convinced that moderators should vote multiple times on a questions (specially if another mod have locked it), we would normally let community moderate these and it's not constructive to force own will. If the question is "at heart" I suggest opening a meta specific for this question and community can decide if it should be open or not.

Comment: In general the question can be both **unclear**, what is OP's actual problem?, is there something specific about a sequence of basic operation they don't understand? **Too broad**, if you need to assume that OP have never programmed in tagged language. Best solution is probably a series of duplicates "How to create list from list" + "How to sum specific values in a List" etc. Overall, it does not add much value to Stack Overflow since it's not really searchable for a person needing exact same thing and an answer would need to cover much more ground to teach a "Never programmed in  python".

Comment: @PetterFriberg The real problem here isn't the specific case, but that various "meta people" push for their own agendas of how to moderate the site. As if they have never used the site before and thereby grasped the community culture/consensus developed over the years. This seems to be a new problem that started this summer, after SO the company abandoned meta. People no longer moderate according to some community consensus, but as they please/at a whim.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TL;DR - Don't rapidly vote to delete questions that can reasonably (even if you have no faith that it would) be edited back into shape.

---

Observations:

- There is an [automated script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/166899) that deletes poorly received questions with no upvoted answers within 9 days of it being closed.
- Heavily downvoted questions have much less visibility than neutral and positively voted ones, so the damage such a question causes is relatively small.

For these two reasons, voting to delete a question that could be stretched to be useful if enough effort was put on it, **even if you have no reason to suspect that the question would ever be improved in practice**, is not only potentially harmful for false negatives like this one, but is honestly not worth your effort or limited number of votes.

Save your delete votes for posts that can never be improved while keeping the original intent. A question like "Which is better, React or Angular?" will never be a good fit on Stack Overflow, no matter how much editorial work is done on it.

The risk of false negatives (deleting a salvageable post) is much greater when deleting these posts manually, than the risk of false positives (keeping an unsalvageable post alive), and even if such an unsalvageable post happens to slip between the gaps, the negative consequences are not great because the system penalizes downvoted/closed questions anyway.

The expected utility from voting to delete on-hold questions is a net loss. I advise everyone to just not do it, and let the system do what it's good at, because it *is* fairly good at this.

Comment: Honestly, ever since getting the delete privilege, I've been confused as to when it should be used. The guidance here is great, but it would be nice if it were spelled out somewhere official.

Comment: This particular question cannot be improved by anyone but the OP. It cannot get "edited into shape". Still not a reason to delete it pre-maturely though.

Answer (score 6):

> OP (which is a new user), posted a question of low quality, and the point of the question was hard to understand.

Not only that, but the actual problematic code isn't present. You can't post a question on SO that just goes like "I want this, I want that". They must post a question about a specific technical problem they are facing. If this problem is related to their attempt to implement the code, we must see the code or we can't help them.

Specifically, in order for a question to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it must fulfil this:

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

(I believe the homework part is a left-over from a time when SO had a specific homework tag, but that one was removed long time ago. *All* questions must fulfil the above, regardless of the reason why someone is asking them.)

The original question had nothing of that and still does not, after several edits.

> I finally edited it by myself, with the elements of the comments.

Still there is not a specific technical problem to solve. This is not a code-writing service where you can post your wish list and get code written for free.

This means that the question is *unsalvagable* by anyone but the OP. A question is first put on hold and then after the OP's been given time to fix it, closed. Since the OP has still not made an attempt to state their specific technical problem, the post will eventually get deleted.

The only problem here was that it got manually deleted a bit too early. Not everyone can respond within hours. The OP should be given a fair chance to fix the question.

> It's a bit frustrating to me because I spent time improving the question, and I had an answer to provide but I wasn't able to because question was on hold.

You can't fix this question, only the OP can. You shouldn't post code answers to questions that are unclear or lacks a specific problem statement. "I want it all and I want it now" is not a question.

Why on earth the question was re-opened, I have no idea. It has been appropriately closed again.

Comment: Just to add onto your answer, even the OP of this question was unsure regarding what the questioner wanted: ['*I **think** that this is not what OP wants and that his sentence is not correct \[...\]*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57752342/how-to-get-the-perform-a-difference-in-each-sublist-of-a-list#comment102009445_57774148). Turned out the OP's interpretation of what was wanted by the questioner was incorrect.